# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'

Tags: telegram-bot, pyrogram

Recently I am getting error in the user_id section where the some random user who is clicking the Buttons which is not meant to be used by himself

Please help solve this error

Code with Error

[image: 1]

I am running a Pyrogram Bot in Telegram
This is where I got the above code error

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `reply_to_message` is None so you cannot extract user_id from it.

I assume you can write

```
user_id = CallbackQuery.message.reply_to_message.from_user.id if CallbackQuery.message.reply_to_message else None
```

to prevent the error from happening.